# Placing appropriate zeros on money values

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way of removing letters and placing the appropriate zeros on money values in my column using pandas. My column is currently like this

```
Salary
$20M
$5.4M
$2.3K
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.Salary=df.Salary.str.replace('$','')
df.Salary=(df.Salary.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
df.Salary.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
.replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))
print(df)
```

---

```
       Salary
0  20000000.0
1   5400000.0
2      2300.0
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '110.5M'. I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack-ish way to do it. Assumes the first character is `$` and the last character is `M` or `K`.

```
M = 1_000_000
K = 1_000
def salary_to_number(s):
    return float(s[1:-1]) * globals().get(s[-1])
```

Output:

```
>>>salary_to_number('$20M')
20000000
>>> salary_to_number('$5.4K')
5400.0
```

Then you can apply this method to the column of your dataframe with `df.apply`